# Ado connection to SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-ce, connection-string, ado, sql-server-ce-4

I want to connect to SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 from an old asp-classic site but i always get the error:

`"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. "`

I tried

```
sCon = "Data Source=c:\temp\sqlcompact.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=testtest;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

and

Update:
Error: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

```
sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\temp\sqlcompact.sdf;Password=testtest;"
```

without any success.

Is it generally possible to connect to SQL Server CE 4.0 from ADO?

Update: 
Example Code
Open Connection:

```
dim sCon

dim gCON : set gCON=CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")

sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\temp\sqlcompact.sdf;Pwd=testtest;"

gCon.ConnectionString = sCon
gCon.Open 
gCon.Close
```

Comment: look here http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: This was my first source when I was looking for the connectionstring but non of them worked for version 4.0

Comment: Post more code: how you actually Open the connection? Looks like you're not using `sCon` properly.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I already connected to Oracle and Sql Server 2008 without problems with different connection strings

Comment: the problem is with the provider most probably.. see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to SQL CE 4 via ADO.

```
Set Cnxn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
strCnxn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;" & _ 
"Data Source=C:\nw40.sdf;" 
Cnxn.Open strCnxn 
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cnxn 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" 
While Not pRS.EOF 
   WScript.Echo pRS(0) 
   pRS.MoveNext 
wend
```

For password protected files, use:

```
strCnxn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;" & 
 _ "Data Source=C:\nw40.sdf;ssce:database password=secret"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the the following provider instead, saw somewhere it's being used with success:

```
sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.SqlServer.Mobile.OleDb.3.0;Data Source=c:\temp\sqlcompact.sdf;Password=testtest;"
```

If no luck, can you create System DSN successfully? If so, create one then use it in the ASP code.

Comment: I had no luck with your connection string but if I use 
`sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=c:\temp\sqlcompact.sdf;"` I can connect now to a 4.0 database but only if the database is not encrypted

Comment: @Yots that's weird.. I fear I have no experience in this so can't help very much. What about DSN? Gave it a try?