# Use VBA to pull SQL CE 4.0 data to latest excel, showing 'method open of object connection failed' error

Tags: excel, sql-server-ce, vba

I was trying to use excel vba to pull some data from a sql ce .sdf file to excel, here are the codes I have used, which comes from Eric's sample post.

```
    Set Cnxn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    strCnxn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Northwind.sdf;"
    Cnxn.Open strCnxn
```

I have checked Microsoft ADO 6.1 Library as reference, but getting a error message saying:
Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed.
Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Is the OLDB provider present in the registry? And what is "Eric's sample post" ?

Comment: Hi, @ErikEJ ! I was using your post from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991694/ado-connection-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0), and I find a registry entry of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. GUID 0C7FF16C- Not sure if this is the one.

Comment: Nope, you should look for the providername Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0 in registry, if not present, install the msi

Comment: Hi, @EricEJ , I found the registry entry, and when installing msi, it also shows that the latest version already exists. But running vba macro still give the same error.

Comment: Do you have write access to the file In the root of C drive?

Comment: @EricEJ, I do have

Comment: Are you sure it is a 4.0 file? Use my Toolbox to check!